# MOngoDB query to groupby with different fields based on condition to return the latest record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to groupby based on condition where my target field can be **sender.category or reciever.category** based on condition that either of those field belongs to "**cat1**", and get the last record of each of on sender.id or reciever.id based on **createdAt**.

Sample Json1:

```
{
    "code" : "34242342",
    "name" : "name1",
    "amount" : 200,
    "sender" : {
        "id" : "fsrfsr3242",
        "name" : "name2",
        "phone" : "12345678",
        "category": "cat1"
    },
    "receiver" : {
        "id" : "42342rewr",
        "name" : "naem3",
        "phone" : "5653679755",
        "category": "cat2"
    },
    "message" : "",
    "status" : "done",
    "createdAt" : "2019-09-27T09:17:32.597Z"
}
```

Sample Json2:

```
{
    "code" : "34242342",
    "name" : "name1",
    "amount" : 200,
    "sender" : {
        "id" : "fsrfsr3242",
        "name" : "name2",
        "phone" : "12345678",
        "category": "cat3"
    },
    "receiver" : {
        "id" : "42342rewr",
        "name" : "naem3",
        "phone" : "5653679755",
        "category": "cat1"
    },
    "message" : "",
    "status" : "done",
    "createdAt" : "2019-09-27T09:17:32.597Z"
}
```

Query:

```
[{$match: {
  $or: [{ "sender.category": 'cat1' }, {"receiver.category" : 'cat1'}]
}}, {$sort: {
  "createdAt": 1
}}, {$group: {
  _id: {sender :"$sender.id", reciever : "$receiver.id"},
  lastrecord: {
    $last: "$$ROOT"
  }
}}]
```

I want to return only the last record, sender.id or receiver.id can have multiple records of which i only want to retrieve the last one. But my query is returning multiple records. 
How to get only the last i.e **latest one based on above conditions and createdAt**?

Sample output:

```
{
            "lastrecord" : {
                "name" : "name1",
                "amount" : 1000,
                "sender" : {
                    "name" : "name2",
                    "phone" : "213232141",
                    "category" : "cat1"
                },
                "receiver" : {
                    "name" : "name",
                    "phone" : "321312412",
                    "category" : "cat2"
                },
                "status" : "done",
                "createdAt" : "2019-11-25T17:00:17.226+06:30"
            }
        }
```

i want this for every sender.id or receiver.id

Comment: Please post a sample output document  (and corresponding input  documents).

Comment: @prasad_ I have posted a sample output doc

Comment: _"... But my query is returning multiple records"_ For each group (of sender and receiver)?

Comment: Yes, it's returning multiple for both

Comment: Then the `$last` selects the last for each group (of sender and receiver). See this example on [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/index.html#example).